# ReWrite Rule Not Working & Causing CSS Errors

Tags: php, css, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm wanting to use the RewriteRule using .htaccess but I'm hitting a bit of a problem with it.  I've tested the rule using:

```
RewriteRule ^newpage articles.php [NC,L]
```

And when I visit `blog.local.com/newpage` i'm shown `articles.php`, so I know that my htaccess is working correctly.

However, when I use:

```
DirectoryIndex articles.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) articles.php?cat=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L]
```

And visit `blog.local.com/articles/all/2`, I'm shown the first articles page, but it's displayed without any CSS styling.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: The problem is that your browser tries to find the CSS files relative to the current page. So, if you call your page at `blog.local.com/articles/all/2` and your HTML says to find `style.css`, it will try to find `blog.local.com/articles/all/style.css`. You need to use absolute paths (`/cssFolder/style.css` or `http://.../style.css`) to your assets when you want to build a page like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `MultiViews` option off.

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex articles.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^articles/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ articles.php?cat=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Also for fixing css/js problem you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thank you, this has certainly fixed the url error.  However I've added `base` to the head section of the pages but I'm still not seeing any styling? Perhaps its because my css is linked in a slightly different way? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../a/css/structure.css">`

Comment: In that case you need to absolute URL for css inclusion. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Or may be try: `<base href="/a/" />`  just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML

Comment: Thank you, you're a genious.  I fixed it using the absolute URL method!  Maybe you could help me with 1 other little problem? I have the php code `$other_sql = "SELECT id, title FROM articles_$blog_id WHERE id != '$post_id' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 8";` to show a list of similar posts, but it's only showing 1.  I have a `.` before the statement (`$show_others .= ".....`) but it still only shows 1.  Is there an error with my original SELECT code?

Comment: If I understand correctly using id in where clause would select only one record from Database. Feel free to post a new question for this using php, MySQL tagged to get better answers.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the `where` clause but it made no difference to the output.  I'll post it as a new question to see if I can get a fix.  Thanks again.